# time format conversion using php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using `datetimepicker` for user input. The format is: `mm-dd-yy hh:mm tt` (Example: `08-25-2014 01:49 pm`). I need to convert it to MySQL `datetime` format using php (Example of same time properly converted `2014-08-25 13:49:00`) for MySQL storage.

```
<?php
$test = '08-25-2014 01:49 pm';
$test = str_replace("-","/","$test");
$test = new DateTime("$test");
$test = date_format($test, 'Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2011-07-01 00:00:00
?>
```

Update: For some reason I had to remove the - and replace it with /. Any idea why forward slashes are fine but not -?

Answer (score 3):

As you are using an American date format and the `-` seperator which is used for NON US date formats, you will probably have to actually do something like this :-

```
$date = '08-25-2014 01:49 pm';

$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->createFromFormat('m-d-Y h:i a', $date);

$date = $dt->format('y-m-d');
```

Comment: I already have the date 08-25-2014 01:49 pm in the variable $date. How do I convert the format and store it to $date?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class:

```
$mydate = new DateTime("08-25-2014 01:49 pm");
$MySQL_format = $mydate->format("m-d-Y h:i a");
```